# Identifying distinct polygons from start and end coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

[snippet of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZcrn.png)

Each ROW represents a line with the 'start' and 'end' rows identifying starting and ending coordinates of the line.

I would like to create another COLUMN that identifies distinct polygons. A polygon is identified by a closed shape. To put in other words, a distinct polygon is identified when the ending coordinates of the last line of the polygon matches the starting coordinates of the first line of the polygon.

I wrote the following loop to perform the comparison and then output a number in a new 'polygon' column:

```
# Initialize counter and array to collect 'start' coordinates
j = 0
check_start = []

# Loop through rows in dataframe df
for i in range(len(df)):
    current = df.iloc[i, 1]           # 'end' coordinates     
    check_start.append(df.iloc[i, 0]) # collecting 'start' coordinates in a list

    # check if 'end' coordinates is in list of 'start' coordinates
    if current in check_start:        
        df.loc[i, 'polygon'] = j      # polygon is closed
        j += 1
        check_start = []              # empty check array to start a new polygon
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'polygon'] = j      # polygon is still open, go to next row
```

**The desired output is a new column 'polygon' that counts up, but I'm getting NaN as a result instead.**

Logic comparing 'current' and the list in 'check_start' seems to check out, so I don't understand how the output in the 'polygon' column ends up as NaN. See snippet below:

[snippet of dataframe with 'polygon' column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roCCh.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem could possibly be related to float comparison, what happens if you turn your coordinates into a string and compare them? But then, everything should at least be 0

Comment: @Nerdrigo

Not sure I follow. I wouldn't expect a match at module0 since that's obviously the start of the polygon.

Since I don't know where the start would be for an n-sided shape, I'm using the check array to collect all the starting coordinate until it finds an ending coordinate that matches. I would expect the first match to occur at module3.

also confused by the NaN result since if there is no match at all, wouldn't it just evaluate to j = 1?

Thanks!

Comment: @Nerdrigo so I attempted to manually compare the ending coordinate with a list of starting coordinates and it evaluates to True, so I don't think it's a float issue

Comment: I just ran your code as is, no changes on a dummy data frame and it worked. start and end columns were much simpler, they were [1,1], [2,2] and the like